# Both http and timer trigger in Azure Function

Tags: python, azure, triggers, azure-functions

I am able to have both a timer and http trigger in my Azure Function by duplicating the project folder. This way I have a seperate `function.json` where I can specify a timer trigger for one and a http trigger for the other, see `src_http` and `src_timer` below:

[image: folders]

This is definitely not desireable, since I am duplicating my code.

**Question**: Is there a way to have both a timer and http trigger in one function?

I read [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/6483) and it looks like this is not possible, I hope I am wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: See some official doc available now on [Folder Structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python#folder-structure) and [Import behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python#import-behavior).

---

In java you can do something like this because it uses `class-name.function-name` as `"scriptFile"` in generated `function.json`:

```java
    public class EhConsumerFunctions {
        private void processEvent(String request, final ExecutionContext context) {
         // process...
        }

        @FunctionName("HttpTriggerFunc")
        public void httpTriggerFunc(
           @HttpTrigger(name = "req", methods = {HttpMethod.GET}, authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS)
           HttpRequestMessage<Optional<String>> req,
           final ExecutionContext context) {
           processEvent(req.getBody().get(), context);
       }

       @FunctionName("TimerTriggerFunc")
       public void timerTriggerFunc(
        @TimerTrigger(name = "timerRequest", schedule = "0 */5 * * * *") String timerRequest,
        final ExecutionContext context) {
           processEvent(timerRequest, context);
       }

    }
```

For python, it takes script name and expects it to have a `main` and separate `function.json`. So you'll have to have two folders and two scripts. But each script can `import` a common business logic module which does the actual processing.

Something like:

```
MyFunctionApp
|____ host.json
|____ business
|     |____ logic.py
|____ http_trigger
|     |____ __init__.py
|     |____ function.json
|____ timer_trigger
      |____ __init__.py
      |____ function.json
```

`http_trigger/__init__.py` will have:

```
from business import logic

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    return logic.process(req)
```

and `http_trigger/function.json` will have:

```json
    {
        "scriptFile": "http_trigger/__init__.py",
        "disabled": false,
        "bindings": [
            {
                "authLevel": "function",
                "type": "httpTrigger",
                "direction": "in",
                "name": "req"
            },
            {
                "type": "http",
                "direction": "out",
                "name": "res"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: This is really helpful, thank you for the extensive response.

Answer (score 2):

Then just don't duplicate your code ;) Move the common code that is used by both Functions into a common class etc. that you reference from the two. The two Functions itself only differ then in their signature (and how they are invoked under the hood).

Comment: I tried this, so I had a different folder with the functional code, let's call this `src`, then made folders `src_http` and `src_timer` where I imported the code from `src`. But I was not able to get this to work since I couldn't import code from a different folder and this `src` folder is not deployed to Azure.

Comment: I'm not big into python tbh but I know that this should definitely work and is not a limitation of Functions.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I will look into this and will post my findings here so others can find this as well. Just to be sure, so you would make three separate folders as well? `src` which has all the functional code of the project. `src_http` where http logic is defined and which imports `src`. Finally `src_timer`, same as http but timer logic.