# Pause/Disable a timer on an Azure Logic App function - difference between the trigger and the function?

Tags: azure-functions

I was doing a simple "Hello world" type logic app in Azure.
I got it working, now I want to stop it.  I don't see any enable/disable button on the timer the triggers it to run.  Do I have to delete the timer?  No way to pause it?

[image]

Looks like it needs to be done at the function level.
Open the "logic app", find the function, click on the elipses ... and select "Disable".

[image]

So this raises a question to me.  Is the function the timer itself? What if I needed two timers on the same piece of code? Can I not have one C# function/program that has multiple triggers?

Comment: A deployed instance of Azure function can have multiple functions in it like multiple timer triggered, queued triggered e.t.c. See [this](https://github.com/amigup/CleanArchitecture-For-AzureFunctionV3/tree/master/CleanArchitecture.Functions/Triggers) for reference which has multiple functions of Http, queue and timer in same instance. 

Another way (apart from you already mentioned by UI) is by application configuration settings; add the `AzureWebJobs.<<Your function name>>.Disabled` setting with `true` value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little unclear on terminology.

Is it a [Timer Trigger Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=csharp), or a [Recurrence triggered](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-recurrence#add-the-recurrence-trigger) Logic App that calls an Azure Function?

- For Timer Triggered Function you already posted the answer, that's how you disable it. You could also click on the Function name, go to it's Overview page and see a `Disable` button if you want to waste some time.
- For a Logic App you have a `Disable` button on Overview page of that app:
  [image]

---

> Is the function the timer itself?

In this context yes.

> What if I needed two timers on the same piece of code?
> Can I not have one C# function/program that has multiple triggers?

A Function can have following binding:

- one trigger
- many output
- many input

See [Both http and timer trigger in Azure Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65090379/both-http-and-timer-trigger-in-azure-function/65099207#65099207) for how to reuse code. But know that if you deploy following code to your Function App, when you look at Portal you'll see two Functions `HttpTriggerFunc` and `TimerTriggerFunc`. This matters more from a Scalability/Deployment etc pov than development.

```java
    public class EhConsumerFunctions {
        private void processEvent(String request, final ExecutionContext context) {
         // process...
        }

        @FunctionName("HttpTriggerFunc")
        public void httpTriggerFunc(
           @HttpTrigger(name = "req", methods = {HttpMethod.GET}, authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS)
           HttpRequestMessage<Optional<String>> req,
           final ExecutionContext context) {
           processEvent(req.getBody().get(), context);
       }

       @FunctionName("TimerTriggerFunc")
       public void timerTriggerFunc(
        @TimerTrigger(name = "timerRequest", schedule = "0 */5 * * * *") String timerRequest,
        final ExecutionContext context) {
           processEvent(timerRequest, context);
       }

    }
```